# How do I exclude the vertical line plotted at a discontinuity?

Tags: plotting

Condsider

```
function = Tan[1 x] + Tan[2 x]
Plot[function, {x, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image]

It has a strong discontinuity around 0.8.

The problem is , if I want to find `function==0`, Mathematica will not only find the real root `x~1.1` , but also a artifact root `x~0.8` Because I think Mathematica created a line around the discontinuity. A single point the has its y value of all values, which I call "a point that is every point".

To make this obvious, let me make a Contour Plot:

```
ContourPlot[function + 2*y == 0, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

We know that only curved line represents real roots. The constant line is the artifact. In fact, if you plot contour for `function + 2*y == 1` or `function + 2*y == 2`, this artifact line remains. Of course, since it is a point that is every point:

```
ContourPlot[function + 2*y == 1, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 100]
ContourPlot[function + 2*y == 2, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]
[image]

So, how to solve the problem in Contour Plot if function to plot has a strong discontinuity that Mathematica tries wrongly (hard) to connect.

Comment: FYI [`FindRoot[function[x] == 0, {x, 1}]`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gImj9.png) gives the right coordinate.

Comment: A starting point is `ContourPlot[function + 2*y == 1, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> {1/function == 0}]`.

Answer (score 2):

If want solution without artefact, then use `NSolve`. And use `Exclusions` to avoid the divergence line

```
f[x_]:=Tan[1 x]+Tan[2 x]
sol=x/.NSolve[f[x]==0 && 0<x<4, x] (*finds all solutions for 0<x<4*)
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}, GridLines -> {sol, {0}}, GridLinesStyle -> Red,  Exclusions -> 1/f[x] == 0]
```

The result you get is `{1.0472,2.0944,3.14159}`, free from a point that is every point.

[image]

You can omit the line that corresponds a divergence from `ContourPlot` also using `Exclusions`.

```
g[x_, y_] = f[x] + 2*y
ContourPlot[g[x, y] == 1, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 100,  Exclusions -> 1/g[x, y] == 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At least with V10 you get the desired results as follows (I can't show the images because my trial version doesn't allow that):

```
function = Tan[1 x] + Tan[2 x];

Plot[function, {x, 0, 1.5}, Exclusions -> Cot[2 x] == 0]

ContourPlot[function + 2*y == 1, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 Exclusions :> Cot[2 x] == 0]

sol = Table[FindRoot[function == 0, {x, i}], {i, 0, 1.5, 0.1}] /. 
 Rule[_, a_] :> Round[a, 0.0001] // Flatten // Chop // Union
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

> {0., 1.0472}

New in V10:

```
NumberLinePlot[function == 0,
 {x, 0, 1.5},
 AspectRatio -> 0.5,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {sol, None}},
 GridLines -> {sol, None},
 GridLinesStyle -> Dashed,
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

PS - You can find the poles with

```
Reduce[function > 10^6, x] /. C[1] -> 0 // N // Flatten // Sort
```

> -2.35619 < x < -2.35619 || -1.5708 < x < -1.5708 || -0.785399 <    x < -0.785398 || 0.785398 < x < 0.785398 || 1.5708 < x < 1.5708 || 
>    2.35619 < x < 2.35619

Comment: You can get the exact positions of the poles (for this function) with `Reduce[Simplify@TrigExpand[1/function] == 0, x]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Perfect - Thank you very much :)