# I need to remove a line from a ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

What happens is that when I make this ParametricPlot:

```
ClearAll [f, g] 

f2 [t_]:= t + 1 / t 
g2 [t_]:= t - 1 / t 
ParametricPlot [{f2 [t], g2 [t]}, {t, 0.00001, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-4, 1}}, ImageSize -> 200] 
ParametricPlot [{f2 [t], g2 [t]}, {t, -80, 80}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 4}}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

The graph of the parametric function appears and additionally appears a straight line through the origin. How I can remove it?

Comment: The line is caused by a discontinuity in your functions at `t == 0`. See these articles in the Wolfram Language Documentation Center: [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exclusions.html) and [`ExclusionsStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html) .

Comment: you may find this answer useful [How do I exclude the vertical line plotted at a discontinuity?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55963/how-do-i-exclude-the-vertical-line-plotted-at-a-discontinuity)

Answer (score 6):

```
ParametricPlot[{f2[t], g2[t]},
 {t, -80, 80},
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 4}},
 Exclusions -> {f2[t] == 0},
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Because

```
FunctionDomain[f2[t], t]
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
ParametricPlot[{f2[t], g2[t]},
 {t, -80, 80},
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 4}},
 Exclusions -> {f2[t] == 0},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed],
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

**Update**

Based upon **Karsten**'s comment and **Michael**'s review a complete solution set could look like this:

```
pg = Point[Transpose[{Re@#, Im@#}]] &[t /. Solve[g2[t] == 0, t]]
```

> Point[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]

```
pf = Point[Transpose[{Re@#, Im@#}]] &[t /. Solve[f2[t] == 0, t]]
```

> Point[{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}]

```
par =
  ParametricPlot[{f2[t], g2[t]},
   {t, -80, 80},
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 4}},
   Exclusions -> t == 0,
   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], {Blue, pf}, {Red, pg}},
   PlotStyle -> Green,
   ImageSize -> 400];

leg =
  SwatchLegend[{Green, Blue, Red}, {"{f2[t], g2[t]} != 0", "f2[t] == 0", "g2[t] == 0"}];

Legended[par, leg]
```

[image]

Comment: Or `Exclusions -> t == 0`

Comment: (+1) very nice answer.

Comment: The only solutions to `f2[t] == 0` are `± I`.  Why would that exclude `t == 0`, which needs to be excluded according to `FunctionDomain`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 (a) `FunctionDomain[f2[t], t, Complexes]` gives `t != 0`. (b) `Solve[f2[t] == 0, t]` gives, as you wisely remarked, `{{t -> -I}, {t -> I}}`.

Comment: You seem to agree that the `Exclusions` condition in your answer does not correspond to the `FunctionDomain` condition.  It seems to me that the `Exclusions` setting is wrong and the `FunctionDomain` is correct.  Is it an accident that `Exclusions -> {f2[t] == 0}` works on the `ParametricPlot`, or is there some explanation that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3):

This is not really any advance on eldo's answer. I post it for illustration:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{t + 1/t, t - 1/t}, {t, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {0}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[{p + 1/p, p - 1/p}]}], {p, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice jump ! Amazing how the point accelerates on the long diagonals :)

Comment: @eldo must admit...jump major reason i posted :)

Comment: `Exclusions -> {0}` seems a quite clear way to address the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = ParametricRegion[{t + 1/t , t - 1/t }, {{t, -80, 80}}];
RegionPlot[r, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 4}}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: As unusual as interesting :)