# Getting rid of vertical lines in plot

Tags: plotting

How can I get rid of red vertical line in below plot? Could any onehelp me?

```
x = 0.1;
tr = -0.0;
dp = -0.2;
xr = -0;
f = dp Cos[2 theta] + tr;
G = 8 I; 
inside = (xr + G dp x Cos[theta] Sin[theta]^2)/f^2 + (1 - 2 tr /f)^2;
lambda1 = f (1 + inside^0.5); lambda2 = f (1 - inside^0.5);
qq1 = Plot[Re[lambda1], {theta, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> ({Red, Dashing[#]} & /@ {Large, Medium})] ;
qq2 = Plot[Re[lambda2], {theta, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> ({Red, Dashing[#]} & /@ {Large, Medium})];
```

Comment: See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65513/plotting-jump-function-without-vertical-lines) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55963/how-do-i-exclude-the-vertical-line-plotted-at-a-discontinuity)

Comment: `How can I get rid of red vertical line in below plot?` what vertical line? I do not see one.  Could you post screen shot showing what you get?  here is screen shot from my PC. 11.2 on windows  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw4QA.png)

Comment: I don't see a vertical line either!?  I am using MMA 11.2 on Mac OS 10.11.6.  Also, can not see vertical line using MMA 11.1.1 on Mac OS 10.11.6

Comment: I can see the vertical lines in Mathematica 10.2.

Comment: @Nasser. Discontinuity exclusion plotting has gotten smatter in recent versions of Mathematica. OP probably using older version.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10.3 @Joseph

Comment: I can not open your screen shot @Nasser

Comment: Could you please help me? @m_goldberg

Comment: A shot in the dark here:  try using AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}  or Axes -> False in your Plot command.

Comment: They didn'tchange anything @Joseph

Comment: Try adding the option `Exclusions -> True`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Solution for version 10.3.1

```
$Version

(* "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)" *)

x = 1/10;
tr = 0;
dp = -1/5;
xr = 0;
f = dp Cos[2 theta] + tr;
G = 8 I;
inside = (xr + G dp x Cos[theta] Sin[theta]^2)/f^2 + (1 - 2 tr/f)^2;
```

Separate `lambda1` into its `Re` and `Im` components

```
lambda1 = f (1 + inside^(1/2)) // 
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify;
```

Extracting the `Re` component

```
lambda1Re = lambda1 /. I -> 0;
```

Use [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) to determine the values for the [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html)

```
FunctionDomain[{lambda1Re, 0 <= theta <= Pi}, theta] //
 Simplify[#, 0 <= theta <= Pi] &
```

[image]

```
lambda2 = f (1 - inside^(1/2));

qq = Plot[{Re[lambda1], Re[lambda2]}, {theta, 0, Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> ({#, Dashing[Large]} &) /@ {Red, Blue}, 
  Exclusions -> {-2*ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]], 2*ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At least for the first plot `qq1` you can find coordinates of discontinuities

```
root1 = theta /. FindRoot[Re[lambda1], {theta, 0.8}]
root2 = theta /. FindRoot[Re[lambda1], {theta, 2.4}]
```

and use `Exclusions` to get rid of the vertical lines

```
qq1 = Plot[Re[lambda1], {theta, 0, Pi}, 
      PlotStyle -> ({Red, Dashing[#]} & /@ {Large, Medium}), 
      Exclusions -> {{theta == root1}, {theta == root2}}];
```

However I could not find roots for `Re[lambda2]`...